# Data frame separation into two frames based on column values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame that has a few columns and rows. I want to separate it into two data frames based on the values in on of the column. Assuming I have three columns: `code`, `blood_cells`, `diabetes`. code values have the following form: `P_001, P_002, P_003, P_004...P_300` I want to separate this data frame into two data frames based on the range of the `code` column. From `P_001 to P_122` and from `P_123 into P_300`. Is this possible?

My second question is, if the `code` column has more of random numbers and I have a list of these random numbers that I want to separate into one data frame, and also separate the rest into another data frame, is this possible too?

```
ID;code;blood_cells;diabetes
1;23;40;yes
2;5;41;no
3;185;50;yes
4;43;51;no
5;97;40;yes
6;2;42;no
```

How can we separate this into two data frames based on `code` column? codes: 23, 5 and 97 into one dataframe and the others into another dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the number and convert it to integer, then use [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to bin your data according to a desired list of bins (here 0->122, 123->300). Finally use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to split the DataFrame:

```
group = pd.cut(df['code'].str.extract('_(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int),
               bins=[0, 122, 300])

dfs = [g for k,g in df.groupby(group)]
```

output:

```
[    code
 0  P_001
 1  P_002
 2  P_003
 3  P_004
 4  P_122,
     code
 5  P_123
 6  P_300]
```

Selecting the DataFrames:

```
dfs[0]
    code
0  P_001
1  P_002
2  P_003
3  P_004
4  P_122

dfs[1]
    code
5  P_123
6  P_300
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code? Does it actually separate the data frame into two? your output still one data frame!

Comment: @bjest I will add comments, and no my output is a list of 2 dataframes

Comment: Thank you. How can I cut it into two data frames if the numbers are random  (i have a list of them). For example, data frame 1 should be [4,8,50, 22, 11...etc.]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example as DataFrame constructor?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have it as a csv file. the difference from the first example is that `code` column has random numbers and I have a list of these numbers.

Comment: Then provide a representative sample of the csv file as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74190849/edit) to your question